# Calling RowCommand "Select" programmatically on a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My goal is to select a row in a gridview according to a request param an open a FormView

*First of all, I get my param in Page_Load:*

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string param_id = Request["id"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param_id))
        {
            SelectRowByDataKeyValue(param_id);
        }
    }
}
```

*Based on this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23587/GridView-selection-by-key) I want to get the corresponding row in my GridView (called gvPrincipal) and select it :*

```
public void SelectRowByDataKeyValue(string value)
{
    gvPrincipal.DataBind();

    int tmpSelectedIndex = 0;
    int tmpPageIndex = 0;

    for (int page = 0; page < gvPrincipal.PageCount; page++)
    {
        gvPrincipal.PageIndex = page;

        gvPrincipal.DataBind();

        for (int key = 0; key < gvPrincipal.DataKeys.Count; key++)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Equals(Convert.ToString(gvPrincipal.DataKeys[key].Value)))
            {
                tmpSelectedIndex = key;
                tmpPageIndex = page;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    gvPrincipal.PageIndex = tmpPageIndex;
    gvPrincipal.SelectedIndex = tmpSelectedIndex;

    gvPrincipal.SelectRow(tmpSelectedIndex);

}
```

Problem 1 : after this, the value is found, gvPrincipal.SelectedIndex is correct but gvPrincipal.SelectedValue gives me most of the time a different value

```
protected void gvPrincipal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Selected Index : {0}, SelectedValue : {1}", gvPrincipal.SelectedIndex, /*wrong value*/gvPrincipal.SelectedValue));
}
```

Problem 2 : In the GridView, the page index is updated as expected but not the row (which should be colored)

*Besides, on each row there is an ImageButton:*

```
<Columns>
...
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnDetail" runat="server" 
                CommandName="Select"
                CausesValidation="False" ImageUrl="~/Images/icon_detail_16.gif"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...
</Columns>
```

*Clicking this button raises gvPrincipal_RowCommand() which sets the FormView in ReadOnly Mode and display detailed informations :*

```
protected void gvPrincipal_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //displays infos
}
```

*FormView Datasource is updated with gvPrincipalValue :*

```
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsfvPrincipalDetail" runat="server" TypeName="crm.dal"
        SelectMethod="SelectElementById">        
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvPrincipal" Name="id" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>          
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

*I want to trigger the same behavior but programmatically in SelectRowByDataKeyValue;
Here is my try :*

```
public void SelectRowByDataKeyValue(string value)
{
    ...

    GridViewRow row = gvPrincipal.SelectedRow;

    ImageButton ImgBtnDetail = (ImageButton)row.FindControl("ImgBtnDetail");

    CommandEventArgs args = new CommandEventArgs("Select", null);

    gvPrincipal_RowCommand(this, new GridViewCommandEventArgs(row, ImgBtnDetail, args));

}
```

Unfortunately nothing happens

Row not remaining unselected is my biggest concern, how can I overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way you can invoke rowCommand manually in C#

**MyGridView_RowCommand(MyGridView, new GridViewCommandEventArgs(imgButton, new CommandEventArgs(imgButton.CommandName, imgButton.CommandArgument)));**

MyGridView is a GridView.
imgButton is ImageButton in particular GridViewRow located in  MyGridView Which i am invoking RowCommand of. I am invoking this RowCommand on CheckBox Which is Also Located in MyGridView but checkbox normally cannot normally handled as image button in row command.

```
    protected void MyCheckBoxInGrid_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;

        GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer);



        if (chk.Checked)
        {


            ImageButton imgButton = row.FindControl("ImgDetail") as ImageButton;
            MyGridView_RowCommand(MyGridView, new GridViewCommandEventArgs(imgButton , new CommandEventArgs(imgButton .CommandName, imgButton .CommandArgument)));
        }}
```

Regards! 
**Zahid Ashraf**